# Difference between int and signed int declaration

Tags: c, types, int, standards, declaration

I am reading some tutorials on embedded programming and one of them says `int` and `signed int` are different but does not explain how or why.

I understand why `unsigned int` and `int` are different but `int` and `signed int` being different is a new one for me.

Comment: That's new to me too. Is said tutorial online? If so, a link would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It is for historical reasons only. Today whenever you declare `int` you get a `signed int`. The only point where you might see a difference even with today's compilers is with `char` versus `signed char` which are different by specification (and notable when assigning a literal string) but not with `int`.

Comment: what is the difference between char and signed char then? Can you please give an example?

Comment: @Anon - the thing is, that it's _undefined_ whether a `char` is `signed` or `unsigned` by default. The standard says nothing about this.

Comment: @Anon The char vs signed char is also historic, early architectures could define it as either and in fact, some architectures used 7 bits only.

Comment: It's implementation-defined whether `char` is a signed type or an unsigned type. And whichever one it is, it's still a different type from `signed char` and `unsigned char` as eznme says. So the standard does say *something* about it, it says that the implementation is required to document whether it's signed :-)

Comment: For the sake of reference, the C99 standard describes this particularity of `char` in **Section 6.2.5 Paragraph 15**. The guarantee that "plain" `int` is *signed* is provided by **Section 6.2.5 Paragraph 4** of the C99 standard.

Comment: "C99 6.7.2.5 Each of the comma-separated sets designates the same type, **_except that for bit-fields_, it is implementation-defined whether the specifier int designates the same type as signed int or the same type as unsigned int.**"  I read that to mean that if you have a bit field of type int, then it can act either as unsigned or signed, depending on the implementation.  So, when using bit fields you probably want to explicitly specify whether it is signed or unsigned.  You would think the same goes for char, short, long, etc. bit fields.  It's safest to be explicit with bit fields.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know the difference exists only for char data type. Where `char a;` can be `signed char a;` or `unsigned char a;` depending on compiler options. As [this article](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka11308.html) says. (--signed_chars)
For int data types, there is no difference between `int` and `signed int`.

Comment: +1, accepting Eznme's answer because he/she replied earlier and same as your answer.

Comment: `char` is never the same type as either `unsigned char` or `signed char`, even though it has the same range and representation as one of them.

Comment: @SteveJessop Could you explain more or point me somewhere i can read about it ?

Comment: @grhegde: The C99 standard is available at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf. Section 6.2.5 defines the built-in types, and paragraph 14 of that section says, "Even if the implementation defines two or more basic types to have the same representation, they are nevertheless different types". C89 and C11 are similar.