# signed int vs int - is there a way to tell them apart in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits, signed

Is there a template or approach which one could use to distinguish between declarations `signed int` and `int`, like in the following example

```
signed int foo;
int bar;
static_assert(magic_signed<decltype(foo)>::value,"signed"); //PASS
static_assert(magic_signed<decltype(bar)>::value,"not signed"); //ASSERT
```

Comment: `int` is `signed` by default.

Comment: Is it intentional that it's called `bar` in the declaration and is then used as `baar`?

Comment: @Blaze - thanks for pointing, fixed

Comment: my belief is no way. after compilation, you can't distinguish between "int" and "signed int", they r the same.

Comment: You cannot distinguish *declarations*. You can distinguish *types*.

Comment: So you have a question which is good, but context is also good. *Why* do you want to be able to tell? What do you foresee that it will help you with?

Comment: @Fantastic Mr Fox - for example in protoc int32 and sint32 are encoded differently. So they have three distinct types - int32, sint32 and uint32. With ability to tell signed int from int it would allow direct mapping between the types in C++ and protoc.

Comment: These are all synonyms:  `int`, `signed`, `signed int`, `int signed`.  They are all the same type.  The ones that omit `int`, the `int` is implicit.  The ones that omit `signed`, the `signed` is implicit.  The order does not matter.

Comment: In this regard, it's `char` that's peculiar: it's implementation-defined whether `char` is signed or unsigned, but it's a distinct type from `signed char` and `unsigned char`. For the other integral types, `signed T` is the same type as `T`.

Comment: Protobuf is not C++. It's a language on its own with types of its own. There's no law of nature that says a natural mapping between Protobuf and C++ types has to exist, and indeed there isn't one. It is your job to provide a mapping that is appropriate for your application.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, that's what I am looking for - means for creating type mapping. Keyword signed could be among them if it would be detectable from templates.

Comment: This makes no sense. In protobuf, int32 and sint32 are different encodings for the same range of  32 bit *signed* integers. They use different encoding to be efficient with different kinds of value distributions. One is more efficient with small positive numbers than with negative or large numbers. The other is equally efficient with all values. C++ has noting remotely similar to that. The application developer needs to map int32_t to either protobuf type, depending on what range of values he expects *that specific variable* to take.

Comment: @n.m. for example, if I declare my C++ member as `unsigned int`, it is written as protobuf's `uint32`, if I use `signed int` or just `int`  - it is written as `sint32` and I have no C++ means yet to specify `int32`

Comment: If your goal is to *find C++ types* suitable for direct mapping for these specific protobuf types, you should have said that in the question. Otherwise the answer is simply "no". The `signed` keyword attached to a C++ declaration (except `char`) has no more meaning than whitespace surrounding it. You cannot detect either in a template or by any.other kind of metaprogramming.

Comment: This seems to be an XY problem. The X is "how do I effectively make use of Protobuf int vs sint distinction when writing C++ code?" The perceived solution Y is "why of course, I write int for int, and signed int for sint". Then Y becomes your new problem. How to distinguish those C++ types? But the solution is wrong to begin with.

Answer (score 5):

Well despite `signed int` and `int` being the same what I think you might have meant is how to tell apart `unsigned int` and `int`.  Take a look at `std::is_signed`.  It is aviable after c++11.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_signed

There is also an `std::is_unsigned`

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_unsigned

If you actually really meant how to tell apart `signed int` and normal `int`, I don't think you can because `int` is implicitly understood to mean `signed int` by the compiler so they are really the exact same thing.

Take a look at this as well.
[Difference between int and signed int declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952553/difference-between-int-and-signed-int-declaration)

Comment: I know how to distinguish unsigned int and int with std::is_signed

Comment: Well then like I said there is no difference between signed and normal int so there is no real point in distinguishing the two.

Answer (score 4):

`int`, `signed int` and `signed` are the same type.

`unsigned int` and `unsigned` are the same type.