# Difference between signed, signed int and int in C++?

Tags: c++, types, int, difference, signed

Is there a difference between the datatypes of `int`, `signed int` and `signed` in C++?

---

And: 
If they would address all the same amount of space in memory (they would be equivalent in the context of memory-allocation), is there a performance difference in compile-/run-time between those (which of course would not be significant for programs like the following but when initializing several hundred variables of that type)?

---

I did a test with any of those to look for if there is any significant difference or any compiler warning or error:

With `signed int`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    signed int a = 5;
    std::cout << "The number entered is " << a << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

With `int`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    std::cout << "The number entered is " << a << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

With `signed`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    signed a = 5;
    std::cout << "The number entered is " << a << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

The output is equivalent for all tests:

```
The number entered is 5
```

---

But that doesn't mean it has to be equal with regards to memory storage and performance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28012943/what-is-the-actual-use-of-signed-keyword

Comment: Every scalar type in C can be either `signed` or `unsigned`, and they are all `signed` by default, so `signed int` and `int` are the same thing. Specifying just `signed` without a type seems wrong, but I think the compilers will default to `signed int` as well.

Comment: Note: 5 is not a particularly good number for a test because it is in range of every standard integral type. What you want to do is poke at the boundary conditions and see if any differ.

Comment: Another related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952553/difference-between-int-and-signed-int-declaration

Comment: Side note: the one peculiarity in the scalars is `char`, which distinguishes `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` as three distinct types.  An unqualified `char` will be platform dependent as to whether it is treated by default as `signed` or `unsigned` (and often compilers provide a switch to change that default behavior).  C++17 has added `std::byte` in `<cstddef>` to help clarify semantic usage of bytes versus characters.

Comment: Also useful, `std::cout << typeid(int).name() << "\n";` can be used to see how the compiler sees the type information of a type or variable.

Comment: @Havenard "Every scalar type in C can be either signed or unsigned, and they are all signed by default" - Not true. `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are 3 *different* and *distinct* types in C++ - and whether `char` is signed or not is implementation defined (and yes, it *does* vary between implementations).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can read about the rules for specifying integer types [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Integer_types).

The first relevant rule is that if you don't provide either `signed` or `unsigned` the compiler assumes `signed`.

> `signed` - target type will have signed representation (this is the default if omitted)

The other rule is that if you provide `signed` or `unsigned` and no size, `int` is assumed. So `int`, `signed int` and `signed` are functionally exactly equivalent.

> `int` - basic integer type. The keyword int may be omitted if any of the modifiers listed below are used.

Edit : You can check the size of types in bytes using the [`sizeof` operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof)  (ex. `sizeof(int)` or `sizeof(a)`) and the range of values a numeric type can represent using [`std::numeric_limits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) (ex. `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`).

Comment: It is also possible to obtain the number of bits in an `int` as `std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits * sizeof(int)`  (assuming a binary target machine).   The use of `<unsigned char>` is important to eliminate effect of the sign bit on number of digits.

Answer (score 3):

These types are exactly the same.  Per [Table 12: simple-type-specifiers and the types they specify](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.type#tab:dcl.type.simple) `signed`, `signed int`, and `int` all have type `int`

The only integer type that you can apply `signed` to that this does not work for (`signed T == T`) is `char`.  There is `char` which is type `char` and `signed char` which is type `signed char`.  If, in your implementation `char` is implemented as a `signed char` code like

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<char, signed char>)
```

will always trigger the assert because even through it is implemented as a `signed char`, because `char` itself is its own distinct type that will only compare the same to `char`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a difference between the datatypes of `int`, `signed int` and
>   `signed` in C++?

No.

Comment: This answer is lacking in proof.

Comment: @user4581301 why ?

Comment: I think it's quite obvious why, lol. It's a one-word answer - perhaps an explanation as to why they are identical would be useful.

Comment: No is the correct answer, but for a good answer you need to demonstrate why the answer is no, preferably with the backing of a trusted reference such as the C++ Standard.

Comment: @user4581301 `signed int` is equivalent to `int` is something that C++ inherits from C. And why it was like that in the first place, maybe only Ritchie or Kernighan knows. That why I answer "No" because nothing more can be explain. And for the reason, I don't add any reference because if he even made a single little effort to search about it in any C++ reference source, he will find this information. I just wanted to make a confirm if he still confuses after searching.